# Extract information from a `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have `Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` returned by `sqc.sql(sqlcmd).collect()`:

```
Array([10479,6,10], [8975,149,640], ...)
```

I can get the individual values:

```
scala> pixels(0)(0)
res34: Any = 10479
```

but they are `Any`, not `Int`.

How do I extract them as `Int`?

[The most obvious solution](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/api/java/Row.html#getInt%28int%29) did not work:

```
scala> pixels(0).getInt(0)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Int
```

PS. I can do `pixels(0)(0).toString.toInt` or `pixels(0).getString(0).toInt`, but they feel wrong...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `getInt` should work. Here is a contrived example as a proof of concept

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3)).map(Row(_)).collect()(0).getInt(0)
```

This return 1

However,

```
sc.parallelize(Array("1","2","3")).map(Row(_)).collect()(0).getInt(0)
```

fails. So, it looks like it is coming in as a string and you will have to convert to an int manually.

```
sc.parallelize(Array("1","2","3")).map(Row(_)).collect()(0).getString(0).toInt
```

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.Row) states that `getInt`:

> Returns the value of column i as an int. This function will throw an exception if the value is at i is not an integer, or if it is null.

So, it will not try to cast for you it seems

Answer (score 2):

The [`Row` class](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.Row) (also see https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.package) has methods `getInt(i: Int)`, `getDouble(i: Int)` etc.

Also note that a `SchemaRDD` is an `RDD[Row]` *plus* a `schema` that tells you which column has which data type. If you do `.collect()` you will only get an `Array[Row]` which does *not* have that information. So unless you know for sure what your data looks like, get the schema from the `SchemaRDD`, then collect the rows and then access each field using the correct type information.

Comment: Well I guess because it's a String? I don't know where your data comes from, but if you look at the schema it should indicate that the first column is of type String.

Comment: Note: in Spark 1.3 the SchemaRDD is called a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is relevant. you dont need to use collect instead you need to call the methods `getInt` `getString` and `getAs` as well in case the datatype is complex

```
val popularHashTags = sqlContext.sql("SELECT hashtags, usersMentioned, Url FROM tweets")
var hashTagsList =  popularHashTags.flatMap ( x => x.getAs[Seq[String]](0))
```